# Linear Impulse values

Tags: java, box2d

I'm creating my own Game Application using Box2D and i'm facing some problems. I managed to render every body i wanted, moving them but i have to put high value to move them correctly. For example here is my Player body definition :

```
    bodyDefPlayer = new BodyDef();
    bodyDefPlayer.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
    bodyDefPlayer.position.set(positionX, (positionY * tileHeight) + 50);
    playerBody = world.createBody(bodyDefPlayer);
    polygonPlayer = new PolygonShape();
    polygonPlayer.setAsBox(50, 50);
    fixturePlayer = new FixtureDef();
    fixturePlayer.shape = polygonPlayer;
    fixturePlayer.density = 0.8f;
    fixturePlayer.friction = 0.5f;
    fixturePlayer.restitution = 0.0f;
    playerBody.createFixture(fixturePlayer);
    playerBody.setFixedRotation(true);
```

And here is how i have to apply my impulse to move him :

```
    Vector2 vel = this.player.playerBody.getLinearVelocity();
    Vector2 pos = this.player.playerBody.getWorldCenter();
    player.playerBody.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(vel.x + 20000000, vel.y * 1000000), pos, true);
```

As you can see my values are pretty high plus the player isn't doing a curve when he is going down but more going straight down when he can.

I'd like to have some help please :)

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are using the Linear Impulse when you should be just applying forces.  The Linear Impulse "smacks" a body with a large force to give it a hefty instantaneous velocity.  This is good if you are hitting a golf ball (large force, small time), or simulating a fired bullet, but it does not look good for the movement of real bodies.

This is a function that I use on my Entities, which are a class to hold the box2D body and apply control forces to the body.  In this case, this function, ApplyThrust, makes the body move towards a target (seek behavior):

```
   void ApplyThrust()
   {
      // Get the distance to the target.
      b2Vec2 toTarget = GetTargetPos() - GetBody()->GetWorldCenter();
      toTarget.Normalize();
      b2Vec2 desiredVel = GetMaxSpeed()*toTarget;
      b2Vec2 currentVel = GetBody()->GetLinearVelocity();
      b2Vec2 thrust = desiredVel - currentVel;
      GetBody()->ApplyForceToCenter(GetMaxLinearAcceleration()*thrust);
   }
```

In this case, the Entity has been given the command to move to a Target position, which it caches internally and can be recovered using `GetTargetPos()`.  The function applies force to the body by generating a difference vector between the desired maximum velocity (towards the target) and the current velocity.  If the body is already headed towards the target at the maximum velocity, the contribution from this function is effectively 0 (same vectors).

Note that this does NOT change the orientation of the body.  There is actually a separate function for that.

*Note the original question appears to be in Java (libgdx?).  This is in C++, but the general idea is applicable and should work in any Box2d implementation by using references instead of pointers, etc.*

There is a code base with [samples of doing this located here](https://github.com/NonlinearIdeas/Missile-Demo).  [You can read more about this code base in this post](http://nonlinearideas.com/smooth-body-rotation-using-pid-control/).  Watch the video...I suspect it will tell you immediately if this is the information you are looking for.

The Normalize function, which should be a member of the b2Vec2 class is:

```
/// Convert this vector into a unit vector. Returns the length.
float32 b2Vec2::Normalize()
{
    float32 length = Length();
    if (length < b2_epsilon)
    {
        return 0.0f;
    }
    float32 invLength = 1.0f / length;
    x *= invLength;
    y *= invLength;

    return length;
}
```

This converts a vector to a unit vector (length = 1) pointing in the same direction.
**NOTE** This is an in-place operation.  It changes the actual b2Vec2 object, it does not return a new object.  Adapt to Java as you see fit.

Was this helpful?

Comment: Hi, I just tried what you answered me. Since it's (i guess) C++ i can't use it. I got some questions. Firstly you have a Vector2 which is supposed to have 2 value and you got only one (first line). Secondly what is supposed to do toTarget.Normalize() ? After that i get it, i tried to use ApplyForceToCenter and it seems to perfectly work, so thanks for the tips :)

Comment: @user2919009 Vec2 = b2Vec2 in box2d.  I'll convert the code.  I just have a typedef for it.  It looks like you are using java (maybe libgdx?).  The code is completely applicable...you just need to do a small conversion for -> to the "." operator, I believe.

Comment: What is supposed to do the toTarget.Normalize() ?
Edit : i just checked out on the net, Vector2 in JAVA doesn't have the normalize function, i'll check in detail what she does or i just gonna skip it.

Comment: I added the function from the C++ code.  I'm surprised it did not make it into the Java code base...it is something of a fundamental operation...

Answer (score 2):

You are using the same units for graphics and physics (pixels). There are two reasons why such approach is bad:

1. It will scale poorly on different resolutions
2. Box2D is tuned to work with some range of values (due to floating number precision). You can find the range of values in Box2D manual. They are in meters there, but how you name the units is actually not important, since Box2D does not keep track of the units, but instead operates on values. For example you can say that the speed of the body is 10 meters per second or 10 foots per second. For calculations it is not important. It will become important when you will interpret the result of calculations. For example, traveled distance over time: in first case it will be meters and in second one foots. But that is not Box2D business. You just pass values to it (For example, `body.pos.set(2, 3) //no info about units here`)

The common technics to overcome these problems is to have different units for use with Box2D and for graphics, and just to rescale between them (look for `PTM_RATIO` in cocos examples)